# Install Microsoft Azure CLI without using Microsoft documentation

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am trying to install Azure CLI as described in Microsoft documentation "Install Azure CLI 2.0"[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#install-on-windows). The documentation seems out-of-date, hard to understand and has many issues associated with it. Each step in the documentation introduces new issues to fix first. An example is shown below.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module AzureRM
Install-Module : The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be load
ed. For more information, run 'Import-Module PowerShellGet'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Module AzureRM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

or

```
PS C:\Users\ostraaten> Import-Module AzureRM
Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureRM' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any mod
ctory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module AzureRM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (AzureRM:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Are there other ways to get Azure CLI? Third-party installers for example. Is there more up-to-date documentation? Better tested documentation?

I cannot use btw the Azure CLI for Linux - which does work - because I need a reserved public static IP address which can only be created using MS Windows CLI for Windows. It also cannot be created through the portal. For reasons unknown.

I also tried the Cloud Shell where CLI is pre-installed but that version is older and doesn't include the method to create reserved IP address. Updating the CLI version in Cloud Shell is also not possible. It fails with an error message.

Comment: Do you want to install Azure CLI 2.0 on your windows PC?

Comment: That is the idea

Comment: Ok, please try to download the MSI and install it.

Comment: It is installed already. It does not seem to be working.

Comment: could you show me the error?

Comment: I added error on Import-Module AzureRM to description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156805/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-onno).

Comment: Use `Import-module AzureRM`  to install Azure PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can download **Azure CLI 2.0 MSI** and install it on your Windows PC.

We can download [MSI](https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCliWindows) here.

---

Update:

If you want to install Azure PowerShell, we can download **Azure PowerShell MSI** [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.4.1-October2017/azure-powershell.4.4.1.msi).

More information, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a difference between the Azure CLI and Azure Powershell.

The command **Install-Module AzureRM** installs the latter.

AzureCLI adds the **az** command. If you open a command prompt and just type **az**, you either see an error or a list of available commands. Note: on Windows 10 you can either install the CLI directly under Windows, or you can install it under the subsystem for linux.

Enabling Ubuntu Bash is described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/):

- Settings -> Update and Security -> For Developers -> Developer Mode
- Control Panel -> Programs -> Windows Features -> Windows Subsystem for Linux

Installing the Azure CLI here is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#install-with-apt-get-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows):

Azure PowerShell is another way of talking to the Azure REST API. The error you're getting indicates there's something wrong with your PowerShell Repository.

Did you verify Azure really isn't installed? You can test this by trying **Login-AzureRmAccount**.

If you get an error you may try **Register-PSRepository -Default** before following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.4.0)